# TypeError: stream is undefined

Tags: node.js, sqlite, reactjs

Can't add a database connection to my small react app, i tried a bunch of npm modules: sqlite, sqlite3, realm. All fall back with type error:

```
TypeError: stream is undefined
```

i do absolutely nothing, just added a require statement in my component case that error:

```
import db from 'sqlite';
```

or:

```
var sqlite = require('sqlite3').verbose();
```

The last trace string:

```
(function (process){
module.exports = function (blocking) {
  [process.stdout, process.stderr].forEach(function (stream) {
    if (stream._handle && stream.isTTY && typeof stream._handle.setBlocking === 'function') {
      stream._handle.setBlocking(blocking)
    }
  })
}
```

and real fails on building, with Error: Cannot find module 'AccessibilityInfo'

Answer (score 1):

Your last trace points to the content of `set-blocking` npm module. Usually it is used by `npmlog`. It requires `process.stderr` and `process.stdout` to be present. In your case they aren't. If you are running the app in Electron that might be the case.

Comment: how do you fix this annoying issue

Answer (score 1):

It probably means that you are attempting to run a `nodejs` library in the browser, and that will not work. You might be able to browserify the library.